# Solid round the number 1!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Solid round the number 1,
> A motley few, this road, walked on,
> Yes I'm a coward now be gone,
> Made of two but I am one!
>
> Submersing ship with unhinged crew,
> Twixt 'Of' and 'Gave' another clue,
> Never in a shade of blue,
> I warn of danger, please don't sue!

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> yellow.

Solid round the number 1,

> The #1 billiard ball is a solid yellow, and "solid" is a term from billiards.

A motley few, this road, walked on,

> An assortment of characters travelled the Yellow Brick Road in the Wizard of Oz (Thanks [Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19547/tom))

Yes I'm a coward now be gone,

> "Yellow-belly" is a synonym of "coward".

Made of two but I am one!

> Yellow light is composed of red and green (Thanks [trentcl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15727/trentcl))

Submersing ship with unhinged crew,

> A submarine is a "submersing ship" and the paradigm submarine is yellow (think the Beatles' album Yellow Submarine).

Twixt 'Of' and 'Gave' another clue,

> "Richard Of York Gave Battle In Vain" is a mnemonic used to remember to names of colors in the visible spectrum: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet. "York" (yellow) comes between "Of" and "Gave" (Thanks [Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19547/tom))

Never in a shade of blue,

> A literal reading: yellow is never blue.

I warn of danger, please don't sue!

> Yellow often symbolizes danger (think traffic lights or yield signs).

Comment: Twixt 'Of' and 'Gave' can be from roygbiv. The road from Wizard of Oz.

Comment: Well done Silenus and @tom +1s all round!  The 'solid' line is spot on without any word play.  Tom's bang on about the road and roygbiv.  made of two is a light thing but the almost-compound-word thing is good too.  the rest are spot on too.

Comment: @Tom I assume you mean "A motley few this road walked on" for the wizard clue. "Made of two" could also be a reference to the fact that yellow light is composed of red and green

Comment: @trentcl - Yep - the characters walking on the brick road. +1's to Brent H and Silenus!

Comment: @trentcl I was just adding the light connection.  +1 for getting it just before I did.

Comment: We don't have yellow cones, so red light and green light give the illusion of yellow light - but it would be equally valid to say that green light is comprised of yellow light and cyan light. I'll get my coat. ;-)